# C# Change computer "description" with Pinvoke

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke

How can I change the description of my local computer (Windows XP) using Pinvoke? I've found a solution for changing the registry directly but id honestly prefer not having to do that. I noticed in Win32_OperatingSystem you can get the description but I don't know what I need to do in order to change the description using this library. In my other Pinvoke examples there was always a method I had to use (containing management objects sometimes).

Edit: Heres the Pinvoke library I was looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239.aspx

Comment: I would just go with the registry method HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\srvcomment

Answer (score 1):

You can use this PInvoke method [NetServerSetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370626(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you pass in 102 for the 'level' parameter, you will need to pass a SERVER_INFO_102 structure to the 'buf' parameter, where you can set the comment (computer description).

Comment: Sorry I was glancing over the documentation.  If you pass in 102 for the 'level' parameter, you will need to pass a SERVER_INFO_102 structure to the 'buf' parameter, where you can set the comment (computer description).  Read the documentation, you'll be able to find what you need.